# How To insert data into SQL Sever with C# without using the database wizard(visual studio)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble inserting data into my table called "client" in my database called "vet".

I'm trying to do the connection manually as opposed to using the database wizard. I want to do it this way so that i can hide the majority of my code in a separate class.

I have a feeling I have the logic for this all wrong as I'm not making use of a data set, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

This is for a school assignment and not for real world use. I have read a number of similar posts but am still unable to come to a solution.

```
public void CommitToDatabase()
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(CLSDatabaseDetails.GlobalConnectionString))
    {
        DataTable client = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string commandString = "SELECT * FROM client";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(client);
        DataRow newClientRow = ds.Tables["client"].NewRow();
        newClientRow["ClientID"] = ClientID;
        newClientRow["FirstName"] = FirstName;
        newClientRow["LastName"] = LastName;
        newClientRow["Phone"] = PhoneNumber;
        newClientRow["CAddress"] = Address;
        newClientRow["Email"] = Email;
        newClientRow["CUsername"] = Username;
        newClientRow["CPassword"] = Password;
        client.Rows.Add(newClientRow);
        da.Update(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: you talk about insert but your code performs select. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: You're instructing SQL to do a `SELECT` but you really need to `INSERT` instead. There are a lot of really helpful sites, I'd suggest the `ADO.NET` tutorial @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Comment: you may need to read this post: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/a72401/using-3-layer-architecture-to-insert-data-into-a-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataSet` is a collection of `DataTable`s. In your example, you're only referring to one table. The `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` method will populate either `DataSet` or `DataTable`. You're calling `da.Fill(client)` which is fine - it will fill the DataTable `client`. You could also call `da.Fill(ds, "client")` which will fill the DataSet `ds`. You can then extract your table via `ds.Tables["client"]`. Using a `DataSet` in this example is overkill, but you can show your tutor how a `DataSet` works.

You're filling the DataTable but then adding the new row with reference to the DataSet. But in your example, the DataSet `ds` has nothing in it, because you filled the DataTable not the DataSet. Try this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string commandString = "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM client";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(ds, "client");
DataTable client = ds.Tables["client"];
DataRow newClientRow = client.NewRow();
... ... ... 
client.Rows.Add(newClientRow);
builder.GetInsertCommand();
da.Update(client);
```

If you only want to insert a row, you don't need to `SELECT` all the rows. If you `SELECT TOP 0 * from client` you'll get the column names (which you need) but without the overhead of returning all the rows.

Comment: Perfect, Exactly what i was hoping for. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public void CommitToDatabase()
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(CLSDatabaseDetails.GlobalConnectionString))
    {
        DataTable client = new DataTable();
        string commandString = "SELECT * FROM client";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(client);
        DataRow newClientRow = client.NewRow();
        newClientRow["ClientID"] = ClientID;
        newClientRow["FirstName"] = FirstName;
        newClientRow["LastName"] = LastName;
        newClientRow["Phone"] = PhoneNumber;
        newClientRow["CAddress"] = Address;
        newClientRow["Email"] = Email;
        newClientRow["CUsername"] = Username;
        newClientRow["CPassword"] = Password;
        client.Rows.Add(newClientRow);
        da.Update(client);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what the source of your data is.  Anyway, here are two examples of moving data from a CSV file to SQL Server and from a DataGridView to SQL Server.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;


public class Form1
{


    private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        dynamic headers = (from header in DataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()header.HeaderText).ToArray;
        dynamic rows = from row in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()where !row.IsNewRowArray.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>.ToArray, c => c.Value != null ? c.Value.ToString : "");
        string str = "";
        using (IO.StreamWriter sw = new IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\OrdersTest.csv")) {
            sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", headers));
            //sw.WriteLine(String.Join(","))
            foreach (void r_loopVariable in rows) {
                r = r_loopVariable;
                sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", r));
            }
            sw.Close();
        }

    }

    private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Dim m_strConnection As String = "server='Server_Name';Initial Catalog='Database_Name';Trusted_Connection=True;"

        //Catch ex As Exception
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        //End Try

        //Dim objDataset1 As DataSet()
        //Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        //Dim da As OdbcDataAdapter
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog OpenFile = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        // Does something w/ the OpenFileDialog
        string strFullPath = null;
        string strFileName = null;
        TextBox tbFile = new TextBox();
        // Sets some OpenFileDialog box options
        OpenFile.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        // Shows only .csv files
        OpenFile.Title = "Browse to file:";
        // Title at the top of the dialog box

        // Makes the open file dialog box show up
        if (OpenFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            strFullPath = OpenFile.FileName;
            // Assigns variable
            strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFullPath);

            // Checks to see if they've picked a file
            if (OpenFile.FileNames.Length > 0) {

                tbFile.Text = strFullPath;
                // Puts the filename in the textbox

                // The connection string for reading into data connection form
                string connStr = null;
                connStr = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; Dbq=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(strFullPath) + "; Extensions=csv,txt ";

                // Sets up the data set and gets stuff from .csv file
                OdbcConnection Conn = new OdbcConnection(connStr);
                DataSet ds = default(DataSet);
                OdbcDataAdapter DataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + strFileName + "]", Conn);
                ds = new DataSet();

                try {
                    DataAdapter.Fill(ds, strFileName);
                    // Fills data grid..
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(strFileName);
                    // ..according to data source

                    // Catch and display database errors
                } catch (OdbcException ex) {
                    OdbcError odbcError = default(OdbcError);
                    foreach ( odbcError in ex.Errors) {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                // Cleanup
                OpenFile.Dispose();
                Conn.Dispose();
                DataAdapter.Dispose();
                ds.Dispose();

            }
        }

    }

    private void Button3_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = default(SqlConnection);
        string connectionString = null;
        string sql = null;

        connectionString = "data source='Server_Name';" + "initial catalog='Database_Name';Trusted_Connection=True";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM [Order Details]";
        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dscmd.Fill(ds);
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);

        cnn.Close();

    }


    private void ProductsDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == DataGridView1.Columns(3).Index && e.Value != null) {
            //
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Value) < 10) {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
            }
            //
        }
        //
    }

    //Private Sub ProductsDataGridView_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
    //    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
    //        Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    //    '
    //    If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn8").Index _
    //        AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
    //        '
    //        If CInt(e.Value) < 5 Then
    //            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
    //            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
    //        End If
    //        '
    //    End If
    //    '
    //End Sub


    //If e.ColumnIndex = ProductsDataGridView.Columns(4).Index _
    //AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
    //'
    //    If CInt(e.Value) = 0 Then
    //        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
    //        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
    //    End If
    //End If

    // ''To (you need to change the column name)
    //    If e.ColumnIndex = ProductsDataGridView.Columns("YourColumnName").Index _
    //    AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
    //'
    //    If CInt(e.Value) = 0 Then
    //        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
    //        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
    //    End If
    //End If


    private void Button4_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable tblReadCSV = new DataTable();

        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("FName");
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("LName");
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Department");

        TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser("C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Employee.txt");

        csvParser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
        csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
        csvParser.ReadLine();

        while (!(csvParser.EndOfData == true)) {
            tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields());
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server='Server_Name';Database='Database_Name';Trusted_Connection=True;");
        string strSql = "Insert into Employee(FName,LName,Department) values(@Fname,@Lname,@Department)";
        //Dim con As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strSql;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "FName");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "LName");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Department");

        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
        int result = dAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV);

    }


    private void Button5_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string SQLConnectionString = "Data Source=Excel-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "Initial Catalog=Northwind;" + "Trusted_Connection=True";

        // Open a connection to the AdventureWorks database.
        using (SqlConnection SourceConnection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString)) {
            SourceConnection.Open();

            // Perform an initial count on the destination table.
            SqlCommand CommandRowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Orders;", SourceConnection);
            long CountStart = System.Convert.ToInt32(CommandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
            Console.WriteLine("Starting row count = {0}", CountStart);

            // Get data from the source table as a AccessDataReader.
            //Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            //    "Data Source=" & "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.txt" & ";" & _
            //    "Extended Properties=" & "text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"","";"

            string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + "C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\" + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No\"";

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection TextConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);

            OleDbCommand TextCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM OrdersTest#csv", TextConnection);
            TextConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader TextDataReader = TextCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            // Open the destination connection.              
            using (SqlConnection DestinationConnection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString)) {
                DestinationConnection.Open();

                // Set up the bulk copy object. 
                // The column positions in the source data reader 
                // match the column positions in the destination table, 
                // so there is no need to map columns.
                using (SqlBulkCopy BulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(DestinationConnection)) {
                    BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Orders";

                    try {
                        // Write from the source to the destination.
                        BulkCopy.WriteToServer(TextDataReader);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                    } finally {
                        // Close the AccessDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy
                        // object is automatically closed at the end
                        // of the Using block.
                        TextDataReader.Close();
                    }
                }

                // Perform a final count on the destination table
                // to see how many rows were added.
                long CountEnd = System.Convert.ToInt32(CommandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
                //Console.WriteLine("Ending row count = {0}", CountEnd)
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} rows were added.", CountEnd - CountStart)
            }
        }


        //Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.csv"
        //Dim TextLine As String

        //If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        //    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        //    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        //        TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
        //    Loop
        //Else
        //    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        //End If

        //Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        //Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        //cmd.Connection = cn

        //cmd.Connection.Close()
        //cmd.Connection.Open()

        //cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipVia,Freight,ShipName,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry) values & OrdersTest.csv"
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        //cmd.Connection.Close()

    }


    private void Button6_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Define the Column Definition                             
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("RequiredDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShippedDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipVia", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Freight", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipAddress", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipCity", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipRegion", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipPostalCode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipCountry", typeof(string));
        using (cn == new SqlConnection("Server='Server_Name';Database='Database_Name';Trusted_Connection=True;")) {
            cn.Open();
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser reader = default(Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser);
            string[] currentRow = null;
            DataRow dr = default(DataRow);
            string sqlColumnDataType = null;
            reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFieldParser("C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\OrdersTest.csv");
            reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
            reader.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
            while (!reader.EndOfData) {
                try {
                    currentRow = reader.ReadFields();
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (currColumn = 0; currColumn <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; currColumn++) {
                        sqlColumnDataType = dt.Columns(currColumn).DataType.Name;
                        switch (sqlColumnDataType) {
                            case "String":
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn))) {
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = "";
                                } else {
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToString(currentRow(currColumn));
                                }
                                break;
                            case "Decimal":
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn))) {
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = 0;
                                } else {
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow(currColumn));
                                }
                                break;
                            case "DateTime":
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn))) {
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = "";
                                } else {
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDateTime(currentRow(currColumn));
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                } catch (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException ex) {
                    Interaction.MsgBox("Line " + ex.Message + "is not valid." + Constants.vbCrLf + "Terminating Read Operation.");
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    //Return False
                } finally {
                    dr = null;
                }
            }
            using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn)) {
                copy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[Orders]";
                copy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
        }

    }


    public static bool GetCsvData(string CSVFileName, ref DataTable CSVTable)
    {
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser reader = default(Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser);
        string[] currentRow = null;
        DataRow dr = default(DataRow);
        string sqlColumnDataType = null;
        reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFieldParser(CSVFileName);
        reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
        reader.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
        while (!reader.EndOfData) {
            try {
                currentRow = reader.ReadFields();
                dr = CSVTable.NewRow();
                for (currColumn = 0; currColumn <= CSVTable.Columns.Count - 1; currColumn++) {
                    sqlColumnDataType = CSVTable.Columns(currColumn).DataType.Name;
                    switch (sqlColumnDataType) {
                        case "String":
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn))) {
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = "";
                            } else {
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToString(currentRow(currColumn));
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Decimal":
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn))) {
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = 0;
                            } else {
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow(currColumn));
                            }
                            break;
                        case "DateTime":
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn))) {
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = "";
                            } else {
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDateTime(currentRow(currColumn));
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                CSVTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            } catch (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException ex) {
                Interaction.MsgBox("Line " + ex.Message + "is not valid." + Constants.vbCrLf + "Terminating Read Operation.");
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
                return false;
            } finally {
                dr = null;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```